# Node-RED Daemon node "Command not running"

Tags: node-red

I am new to Node-RED and I am trying to run a python script that involves asking user inputs from stdin. I'm trying to use Daemon node as it's specifically designed for long-running processes. The image shows a simple structure that I experiment on to get it running.

I connect a button to the Daemon node and forward the stdout to a debug node for viewing the message, but the only output I get was "command not running". The python script is stored at `/example/main.py`. Did I miss anything or did I misunderstand the Daemon node? Any help would be appreciated!

[image: Daemon Node]

Comment: Is `main.py` executable, does it have a `#!/usr/bin/eval` line at the start?

Comment: No. The python script is at a directory in the home directory -- `/home/example/main.py`. I usually run it by just entering `python /home/example/main.py` through command line. How should I apply this to the daemon node? I also tried putting `/usr/bin/python` in the command field, and `/home/example/main.py/` in the arguments field, but got the same `command not running` error. Thanks!